# Simulink how to reproduce code generation bugs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am interested in reproducing a Simulink bug reported in their [official site](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1290600). The bug is marked as a *code generation* bug. From my limited understanding, Simulink generates code when run in *accelerator* or *rapid accelerator* [modes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-simulation-mode.html). Alternatively, I can generated code using `Code` > `C/C++ Code` > `Build Model` menu option but I do not now how to "run" this code in my Desktop computer.

To reproduce this bug (and possibly all other bugs categorized as *code generation* bugs), will it be sufficient to run simulation in these modes (accelerator or rapid accelerator mode) where Simulink generates code? Once the code is generated (in a directory called "slprj"), will these code suffer from the bugs reported?

Or, should there be any other approaches for generating code to reproduce this bug? I have never used the code generation feature of Simulink and only know that I can generate code for a model using "Code" menu (`Code` > `C/C++ Code` > `Build Model`). For this particular [bug](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1290600), I was able to use the above menu options and generated code (not in "slprj" directory, in a different directory which has `_ert_rtw` prefix). Should I inspect code in this directory? Also, I would like to know how to run this code to reproduce the bug.

Thank you for any advices!

Comment: It is a bug in the embedded coder, not in the simulink coder. From your question I assume you are only using the simulink coder.

Comment: Yes, you should look at code in _ert_rtw directory. Depending on target you may get an executable in that directory which you can run.

Comment: @Daniel can you please explain difference between embedded coder and simulink coder. Should I be able to reproduce it when I generate code using any one of the methods mentioned above (and potentially running it in the Desktop environment)?

Comment: @Navan thanks. Yes I get an executable (in my 64bit Linux desktop) in the directory of the model, but when I run it it prints following message and does nothing (seemingly) unless I press ctrl+c: `Warning: The simulation will run forever. Generated ERT main won't simulate model step behavior. To change this behavior select the 'MAT-file logging' option.`

Comment: I found the differences between various coders: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12091-difference-between-simulink-coder-embedded-coder-and-matlab-coder

Comment: Did you try to reproduce it using the embedded coder?

Comment: @Daniel yes. Here is what I did: I chose `ert.tlc` as "System Target File" in the code generation panel (from `Configuration Parameters` dialogue). Then I used `Code` > `c/c++ code` > `Build Model` menu to generated code and manually inspected it. But the generated code did not reflect the bug report: it contained the `memset()` calls in the code for initializing the subsystem present in the given model.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I assumed you don't not have a license for the embedded coder.

Answer (score 1):

This bug seems to be a missing initialization in the generated code which you can verify by investigating the generated code. Try to reproduce in the model attached to this bug report. However, in order to check the correctness between the model simulation result and the generated code, I would recommend using SIL based testing which is described here:

https://in.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/examples/software-and-processor-in-the-loop-sil-and-pil-simulation.html